# WPF XAML form generated on the fly - how to reference xaml elements later

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, dynamically-generated

I have some powershell code where i am leveraging a xaml template to generate a grid of servers.  Since the number of servers and names will change (fed from a spreadsheet) i am not able to hardcode the names of the XAML elements.

I am able to generate the grid (server items grouped by types of servers) successfully without any issues.  my issue now is **how to reference the XAML items generated 'on-the-fly'** later.  I feel like this is a relatively easy question based on the complexity of what i am already doing, but i am new to working with XAML, especially generating a XAML form on the fly.

Here is the XAML template and the two functions that generate the xaml items on the fly.

```
    [xml]$xaml = @'
    <Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title='MainWindow' Height='Auto' Width='Auto' FontSize='9'> 
    <Window.Resources> 
        <Style x:Key="GroupBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
                        <Grid>
                          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                          <Border Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                  BorderThickness="1"
                                  BorderBrush="#25A0DA"
                                  Background="#25A0DA">
                              <Label Foreground="White">   
                                  <ContentPresenter Margin="4"
                                              ContentSource="Header"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                              </Label>
                          </Border>
                          <Border Grid.Row="1"
                                  BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                                  BorderBrush="#25A0DA">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                          </Border>
                        </Grid>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility ='Auto' ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ='Auto'>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="False" Name='StartingGrid'>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button 
                Name='Refresh_Btn' 
                Content='Refresh' 
                Width='70'
                Height='30'
                FontSize="9" 
                FontWeight="Bold" 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.Row="0"/>

            <Button 
                Name='Reboot_Btn' 
                Content='Reboot' 
                Width='70'
                Height='30'
                FontSize="9" 
                FontWeight="Bold" 
                Grid.Column="1" 
                Grid.Row="0"/>

    </Grid> 
 </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
'@

Function CreateServerGrid{
    $srv = $Srv.name
    $grd = New-Object system.windows.controls.grid
    $grd.Name = "Server" + ($counter)
    #$grd.ShowGridLines = 'True'
    $row1 = new-object system.windows.controls.rowdefinition
    $row1.height = "Auto"
    $row2 = new-object system.windows.controls.rowdefinition
    $row2.height = "Auto"
    $row3 = new-object system.windows.controls.rowdefinition
    $row3.height = "Auto"

    $col1 = new-object system.windows.controls.columndefinition
    $col1.width = "Auto"
    $col2 = new-object system.windows.controls.columndefinition
    $col2.width = "Auto"
    $col3 = new-object system.windows.controls.columndefinition
    $col3.width = "Auto"

    $grd.RowDefinitions.add($row1)
    $grd.RowDefinitions.add($row2)
    $grd.RowDefinitions.add($row3)

    $grd.ColumnDefinitions.add($col1)
    $grd.ColumnDefinitions.add($col2)
    $grd.ColumnDefinitions.add($col3)

   $ServerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Label
   $ServerLabel.Name = "$srv"
   $ServerLabel.FontWeight = "UltraBold"
   $ServerLabel.Content = $srv
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($ServerLabel,0)
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($ServerLabel,0)
   $ServerLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'Right'
   #RegisterName($srv.name,$ServerLabel)
   #$GUIhash.Add($_.TargetType,$_)

   $ItemLabel0 = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Label
   $ItemLabel0.Name = "Label_LastDeployment_$srv"
   #$ItemLabel1.Height = "Auto"
   $ItemLabel0.Content = "Last Deployment:  " 
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($ItemLabel0,1)
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($ItemLabel0,1)

   $ItemText0 = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.textBox
   $ItemText0.Name = "LD_$srv"
   #$ItemLabel1.Height = "Auto"
   $ItemText0.text = "OtherData1 " + ($counter + 2 )
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($ItemText0,1)
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($ItemText0,2)

   $ItemLabel1 = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Label
   $ItemLabel1.Name = "Label_LastReboot_$srv"
   #$ItemLabel1.Height = "Auto"
   $ItemLabel1.Content = "Last Reboot:  "
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($ItemLabel1,2)
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($ItemLabel1,1)

   $ItemText1 = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.textBox
   $ItemText1.Name = "LR_$srv"
   #$ItemLabel1.Height = "Auto"
   $ItemText1.text = "OtherData1 " + ($counter + 2 )
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($ItemText1,2)
   [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($ItemText1,2)


    $grd.AddChild($ServerLabel)
    $grd.AddChild($ItemLabel0)
    $grd.AddChild($ItemText0)   
    $grd.AddChild($ItemLabel1)
    $grd.AddChild($ItemText1)   


    return $grd

}

Function StartTheFun {

    $script:counter = 1 

foreach ($grp in $grouping){ 
   $WPFStartingGrid.RowDefinitions.add((new-object System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition -property @{ Height = 'Auto'}))

   If($Counter -eq 3){
    $script:cnt ++
    $WPFStartingGrid.ColumnDefinitions.add((new-object System.Windows.Controls.ColumnDefinition -property @{ Width = 'Auto'}))
    $script:counter = 1 
    }
   $grid =@()

   $newStkPnl = new-object System.Windows.Controls.Grid

   $NewGB = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox
   $NewGB.Header = $grp
   $NewGB.Margin = "0"
   $init = 0
   $ct = 0
   $srvCnt = ($list | ?{$_.'Computer_Description' -match $grp}).count
   #Write-Host $grp
   #Write-Host "ServerCount:  " $srvCnt
   $CntCheck = $false
   if ($srvCnt -gt 4){$CntCheck = $true}
   #Write-Host "CntCheck:  " $CntCheck 

   foreach ($srv in $list | ?{$_.'Computer_Description' -match $grp}) {
        Write-Host 'Server:  ' $srv.name
        Write-Host 'Init:  ' $init
        $newStkPnl.RowDefinitions.add((new-object System.Windows.Controls.RowDefinition -property @{ Height = 'Auto'}))
        #$ControlObj.Add($srv.Name,$_)
        $grid = CreateServerGrid $srv
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($grid,$init)
        [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($grid,$ct)
        $newStkPnl.AddChild($grid)
        $init ++
        $srvCnt --
        if($srvCnt -gt 0){
            If ($init -gt 3){
                    $newStkPnl.ColumnDefinitions.add((new-object System.Windows.Controls.ColumnDefinition -property @{ Width = 'Auto'}))
                    $ct ++
                    $init = 0
                }
            If (($srvCnt -gt 0) -and ($init -eq 0)){
                    $newStkPnl.ColumnDefinitions.add((new-object System.Windows.Controls.ColumnDefinition -property @{ Width = 'Auto'}))
                    $ct ++
                    $init = 0
                }
        }


        Write-Host 'NewSrvCnt:  ' $srvCnt
        }

   $NewGB.Content = $newStkPnl
   $NewGB.Name = 'Group' + ($counter)
   $NewGB.Style = $GuiHash.Window.FindResource("GroupBoxStyle1")
    [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetRow($NewGB,$counter)
    [System.Windows.Controls.Grid]::SetColumn($NewGB,$cnt) 
   $Script:counter ++
   $WPFStartingGrid.AddChild($NewGB) 
   }


    }
```

Any ideas on how to best reference these elements?  I am providing an image so people can see what it looks like when it runs.

[image]

Comment: It seems as though you are manipulating the UI elements directly. You might want to consider some kind of UI element that has an `ItemsSource` property -- such as `DataGrid` or perhaps `ListBox`, depending on your needs -- and set the `ItemsSource` to `$grouping`. Then, you can set the ItemTemplate to the XAML appropriate for each item in your collection.

Comment: I may not fully understand, The grouping is just to keep like things together, and when you get to the server item that is where we start to 'check things'  Are you suggesting that i return the data i need per server in a data grid?  i didn't think i would be able to bring different data types into a single grid.  The example i have above is just a very small subset of data (last reboot/last patch deployment) that needs to be checked on all the servers, 

If i could run the logic i need against all the data returned in a DataGrid i suppose it would work.  Can you give a link to an example?